# My VideoPlayer Activity stopped working (VideoView)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-contentprovider, android-videoview

My vidéo player activity has stop working well without any code modification for months.

I don't really know when it stopped working but I feel like it's due to the `ContentProvider` that I added recently for 7+ compatibility on intent.

The symptom is that `progressDialog` is never hidden. Indeed neither `onPrepared` nor `onError` is ever called. I just get an endless spinner.

Also note that weather it's a local file of a streamed one, the exact same thing append.

Do you think it could have something to do with my recently added contentProvider? Or I should search in an other way?

It's a quite short activity:

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends M360Activity {

public static final String TAG = "VideoPlayerActivity";

public static final String VIDEOS_URL = AppConstants.SERVER_URL + "/hls/videos/mp4:";
public static final String VIDEOS_SUFFIX = ".mp4/playlist.m3u8";

private static final String ARG_VIDEO_MEDIA_ID = "F9mmPRCFhpQfNtk826ye";

private VideoView videoView;
private String mVideoId;
private Media mMedia;
private MediaController mControls;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private int position = 0;

private int buttonPosition = HQ;
private Button qualityButton;
private String bitRateMobile;

public static Intent newIntent(Context c, String mediaId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(c, VideoPlayerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(VideoPlayerActivity.ARG_VIDEO_MEDIA_ID, mediaId);
    return intent;
}

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

    mVideoId = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_VIDEO_MEDIA_ID);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate id : " + mVideoId);

    mMedia = realm.where(CourseElement.class)
            .equalTo("childType", CourseElementTypes.MEDIAS.name())
            .equalTo("id", mVideoId)
            .findFirst();

    if (mControls == null) {
        mControls = new MediaController(VideoPlayerActivity.this);
    }

    // create a progress bar while the video file is loading
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoPlayerActivity.this);
    // set a name for the progress bar
    // set a message for the progress bar
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    //set the progress bar not cancelable on users' touch
    //progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    // show the progress bar
    progressDialog.show();

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    videoView.setMediaController(mControls);

    if (mMedia != null) {
        bitRateMobile = mMedia.getBitrateMobile();
    }

    qualityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quality_button);

    if (FileManager.getMediaFile(mMedia) != null && FileManager.getMediaFile(mMedia).exists()) {
        runOnUiThread(new MainThreadLoadVideo(FileManager.getMediaFile(mMedia).getAbsolutePath()));
        qualityButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        new Thread(new BackGroundRunnable()).start();

        qualityButton.setText(buttonPosition == HQ ? getString(R.string.hq) : getString(R.string.sq));

        qualityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                videoView.pause();
                position = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
                progressDialog.show();
                new Thread(new BackGroundRunnable(buttonPosition)).start();
                if (buttonPosition == HQ) {
                    qualityButton.setText(getString(R.string.sq));
                    buttonPosition = SQ;
                } else {
                    qualityButton.setText(getString(R.string.hq));
                    buttonPosition = HQ;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public static int HQ = 0;
public static int SQ = 1;
public static int DEFAULT = -1;

private class BackGroundRunnable implements Runnable {

    int quality = DEFAULT;

    public BackGroundRunnable() {
    }

    public BackGroundRunnable(int quality) {
        this.quality = quality;
    }

    @Override public void run() {

        String path = null;

        if (quality == DEFAULT && bitRateMobile != null) {

            ConnectionQuality cq = ConnectionClassManager.getInstance().getCurrentBandwidthQuality();
            switch (cq) {
                case POOR:
                case MODERATE:
                case UNKNOWN:
                    path = VIDEOS_URL + mVideoId + "@480p" + VIDEOS_SUFFIX;
                    break;
                case GOOD:
                case EXCELLENT:
                    path = VIDEOS_URL + mVideoId + VIDEOS_SUFFIX;

                    break;
            }
        } else if (quality == SQ) {
            path = VIDEOS_URL + mVideoId + "@480p" + VIDEOS_SUFFIX;
            qualityButton.setText(getString(R.string.hq));
            buttonPosition = HQ;
        } else {
            path = VIDEOS_URL + mVideoId + VIDEOS_SUFFIX;
            qualityButton.setText(getString(R.string.sq));
            buttonPosition = SQ;
        }

        runOnUiThread(new MainThreadLoadVideo(path));
    }
}

private class MainThreadLoadVideo implements Runnable {

    String path;

    public MainThreadLoadVideo(String path) {
        Log.i(TAG, path);
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        try {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);



            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    // close the progress bar and play the video
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    //if we have a position on savedInstanceState, the video playback should start from here
                    videoView.seekTo(position);
                    videoView.start();
                }
            });

            videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(VideoPlayerActivity.this).setTitle(
                            getString(android.R.string.VideoView_error_title))
                            .setMessage(getString(android.R.string.VideoView_error_text_unknown))
                            .setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                                @Override public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            })
                            .create()
                            .show();

                    return true;
                }
            });
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //we use onSaveInstanceState in order to store the video playback position for orientation change
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Position", videoView.getCurrentPosition());
    videoView.pause();
}

@Override public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //we use onRestoreInstanceState in order to play the video playback from the stored position
    position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
    videoView.seekTo(position);
}
```

and my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.m360.android.activity.VideoPlayerActivity"
    >

  <View
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/grey_900"
      />

  <VideoView
      android:id="@+id/video_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:visibility="invisible"
      />


  <Button
      android:id="@+id/quality_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
      tools:text="HQ"
      style="@style/MainButton"
      />

</merge>
```